# Unit test to catch incorrect implementation

Tags: python, unit-testing

The other day I was watching a lecture by Scott Wlaschin on property-based unit tests and I thought it was great. Totally new concept for me, but it was easy to understand. If interested, you can find [the lecture on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYzDFHx6QPY&t=1559s).

One of the examples Scott went through was the incorrect implementation of a simple addition function and property-based tests that allow to catch it. Standard properties of addition were used - commutative, distributive, etc.

All this worked well, but I was thinking and what if I decided to implement addition in this strange way:

```py
import random
from math import log

def technically_not_a_sum(x, y):
    i = random.randint(1e10, 1e15)
    t = i**x * i**y
    return log(t, i)
```

Technically, the addition is not implemented or implemented but in a very horrific and inefficient way. Yet, it passes all property-based tests with no issues.

```py
def test_is_commutative():
    x = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    y = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    
    assert round(technically_not_a_sum(x, y), 5) == round(technically_not_a_sum(y, x), 5)
    
def test_is_associative():
    x = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    y = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    z = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    
    assert round(technically_not_a_sum(x, y) + z, 5) == round(technically_not_a_sum(y, z) + x, 5)
    
def test_is_identity():
    x = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    y = 0
    
    assert round(technically_not_a_sum(x, y), 5) == x
    
def test_is_distributive():
    x = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    y = round(random.random()*10, 5)
    z = round(random.random()*10, 5)

    assert round(technically_not_a_sum(x, y)*z, 5) == round(x*z + y*z, 5)
```

Is there any way to catch this particular implementation with unit testing? Or is this not specifically a correct problem for unit testing?

Comment: Well, you just showed that an addition is not only defined by these properties. What about testing something like 1+1=2?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, well, of course it passes "1+1=2".

Comment: Ah sorry, wait - I see now that you really do addition. In this case, your tests pass as they should. Your solution is correct, just slow, and performance problems are generally not handled using unittests.